# Show that a certain set is an open set in C[a,b]

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I need to show that the set
$$
R_n = \bigg\{f\in C[a,b]: \forall x\in [a, b]\exists h>0 \bigg(\bigg|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\bigg| > n\bigg)\bigg\}
$$
is an open set on the metric space $(C[a,b], d)$, where $C[a,b]$ are all continuous real functions on closed interval $[a,b]$, and the metric $d$ is  $$d(f,g) = \max_{a\le x \le b}|f(x)-g(x)|$$

I tried to solve this problem for hours but couldn't make it... The solution simply says that it can be shown by using the definition of $R_n$ and the compactness of $[a,b]$. I tried to estimate
$$
\bigg|\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}\bigg| > \bigg|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\bigg| - \bigg|\frac{g(x+h)-f(x+h)}{h}\bigg| - \bigg|\frac{g(x)-f(x)}{h}\bigg|
$$

For a certain $f\in R_n$ , if I traverse all $x\in [a,b]$ I get the corresponding $h=h(x)$ and $K(x) = |(f(x+h)-f(x))/h|$, if I can somehow show that $\sup K(x) > n$ and $\inf h(x) > 0$, I can use the inequality above to construct a valid $\epsilon$, so that the open ball $B(f, \epsilon)$ is contained in $R_n$. However I failed to show this.

Can anyone help solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If x=b, wouldn't x+h be out of the function's domain?

Comment: @billy9797 sorry, it should be [a, b-1/n]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(There is a minor problem in the definition of $R_n$.
You need to choose something like $C[a, c]$ with $c > b$ as ambient space, for otherwise the definition of $R_n$ is not well posed.)

Let $f\in R_n$.
Since $f$ is continuous, the condition in the definition of $R_n$ can be rewritten as:
$$
\forall x\in [a,b]\ \exists h(x) > 0, \ \exists \delta(x) > 0, \exists \epsilon(x) > 0:
\quad
\left|\frac{f(y+h(x))-f(y)}{h(x)}\right| > n + \epsilon(x)\quad
\forall y \in B_{\delta(x)} (x).
$$
Since $[a,b]$ is compact, you can find $x_1, \ldots x_m\in [a,b]$ such that
$$
[a,b] \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^m B_{\delta_i}(x_i),
\qquad \delta_i := \delta(x_i).
$$
Choosing
$$
\epsilon := \min_{i=1,\ldots,m} \epsilon(x_i)
$$
you have that every $g\in C[a,b]$ with $\|g-f\|_\infty < \epsilon$
belongs to $R_n$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I came across the idea that such a $B_\delta(x)$ exists for any $x$ but didn't think about constructing a open cover.